# How to make wsl2 from stopped to running on Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I have installed docker recently on my machine. And later installed ubuntu, to install this I have had problems with windows update and anyhow I installed ubuntu.

But now wsl is in a "Stopped" state and I want it to be in a "running" state. I have tried on/off of features- wsl and virtual machine platform and the whole step again but still it is in "stopped" state.

I have tried online as well I couldn't get it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYsQc.jpg

The screenshot of PowerShell is attached above for reference

Windows-10 Machine

Comment: I struggled a lot with this too. The best docker/wsl integration is in the latest release of Windows (you have to get a Windows insider account and enable insider software updates).

Comment: Can you tell me the steps in detail

Comment: had the same issue. What I did is restart the wsl from powershell terminal using this command 

wsl --shutdown
wsl

open ubuntu terminal again and problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend running the following command.

`wsl -d ubuntu`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This did the trick for me, switching from "legacy" WSL 1 (previously running) to "ubuntu" WSL 2 (previously stopped).

Answer (score 1):

I once encountered a similar issue. 
The only solution for me was to uninstall and reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: It's not about ubuntu but docker as well